# excel - determine number of rows used in a formula of another cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

i have cell A1 with formula: `=SUM(J16:J115)`
and i want to have another cell determine the number of rows in cell A1.

so lets say cell A2 will do something like

> ROWS("refer to the range used in A1, J16:J115")

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem. Might be useful to share some sample data, and possibly we can recommend a better approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option using `FORMULATEXT`, `ROWS`, `SUBSTITUTE`, and `INDIRECT`:

```
=ROWS(INDIRECT(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(FORMULATEXT(A1),"=SUM(",""),")","")))
```

[image]

Though, one has to ask why you want to do this, and parsing formulas like this is a very fragile approach.

Also note that `INDIRECT` is volatile and should be avoided, or at least used only sparingly.

Comment: Not posting it as an answer. but only an alternative without using `INDIRECT()` --> `=LET(a,SUBSTITUTE(TEXTSPLIT(FORMULATEXT(A1),{"=SUM(",")"},":",1),"J",)+0,
b,INDEX(a,1)+0,
c,INDEX(a,2)+0,
c-b+1)`

Answer (score 1):

You probably should use a named range here. (I'm using a non-English Excel for this, so some command names may be off. Any corrections are appreciated.)

Select `J16:J115`, right click and select "Define name...". Type in a name, say `Example`. Now use this in `A1` instead (`=SUM(Example)`) and in `A2` use it with `ROWS`: `=ROWS(Example)`.